# Copy multiple files with glob from a list of wild cards

Tags: python, file, copy, glob, shutil

In Python, is there a way to copy lots of files which are found using wildcards, all of which are stored in a list?

For example say the files I wanted to open are contained in a folder with filenames:

```
test1.txt, test2.txt, test3.txt ... testN.txt
```

And I wanted to copy files using a list which has know properties of the files, for example here:

```
wildcards = [2,3]
```

...so I would like to copy files: "test2.txt" and "test3.txt" only.

In my mind this would operate somewhat like the following:

```
import shutil
import glob

def file_mover(some_list):
        path_load = '/Documents/data/'
        path_save = '/Documents/moved/'
        filenames = some_list
        for filename in glob.glob(path_load+ str(*filenames) +'*.txt'):
                shutil.copyfile(path_load+filename,path_save+filename)

file_mover(wildcards)
```

Obviously this will not work but it gives you an idea of the kind of operation I'm trying to accomplish.

Comment: First, do not call your variable/parameter `list` because it is a built-in function. Second, would you please give an example of how you would call `file_mover`?

Comment: `filter` the list and then `map` the `copyfile` operation to the survivors.  Alternately, do this in your OS command line -- the OS is *built* to do this type of operation.

Comment: @HaiVu: Apologies, this is more of a pseudo code example but I've implemented the changes which should help explain it better.

Comment: @Prune : do you mean generate a list of all filenames and then remove all the ones that aren't in the wildcard list? Perhaps  I should look at OS

Comment: Sorry; inelegant wording.  No, I mean to use your regex as the filter, just as you've done.  However, issuing an `os` command is likely far more reliable, and even faster.

Comment: I've never used OS before but I'll check it out and see if I can use it

Comment: What does `some_list` looks like? It is hard to write a function if we don't know what the input looks like. That is why I asked how you would call `file_mover`.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.. I've written the list as [2,3], called it 'wildcards' and even called it using the function file_mover(wildcards)